# How to print new line character with echo?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, newlines, echo

I dump a string with `hexdump` like this `2031 3334 2e30 0a32 2032 3331 302e 000a`. It is clear that `0x0a` is new line character, however, when I try to echo this string out, I always got `1 430.2 2 13.0` -- the new line is replaced with a space, even I use the `-e` flag.

What may be the problem? Does the tailing `\0` ruin the output? Is there any alternatives to print `0x0a` a new line?

Thanks and Best regards.

Comment: *when I try to echo this string out* How exactly do you do that? What is the exact command you use?

Comment: @Dennis I mean `echo -e`. Thanks, I find a solution.

Comment: the preferred solution is just to use `printf "...\n"` instead of `echo`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467424/echo-new-line-in-bash-prints-literal-n

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The new line character with the `echo` command is "\n". Taking the following example:

```
echo -e "This is line 1\nThis is line 2"
```

Would result in the output

```
This is line 1
This is line 2
```

The "-e" parameter *is* important here.

Comment: btw, this `"echo -e ..."` relies on bash's echo to work correctly (e.g., `dash` will just print the "-e"); but '/bin/echo' may (or may not) also work. Unfortunately (perhaps appropriately), there are a lot of echo's around, and you don't really want to care about which one you're going to get. Using `'printf "....\n"` is a more portable option across env's and shells.

Comment: @michael_n which is [what the OP finally reverted too](http://superuser.com/a/444220/143340), in fact. But the question was explicitely stating "with echo" – hence my answer this way. Anyhow, it was not "with Bash" – so thanks for your pointing out those differences!

Answer (score 5):

**POSIX 7 says you can't**

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html

`-e` is not defined and backslashes are implementation defined:

> If the first operand is -n, or if any of the operands contain a <backslash> character, the results are implementation-defined.

unless you have an optional XSI extension.

So use [`printf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) instead:

> format operand shall be used as the format string described in XBD File Format Notation [...]

the [File Format Notation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap05.html#tag_05):

> \n <newline> Move the printing position to the start of the next line.

Also keep in mind that Ubuntu 15.10 and most distros implement `echo` both as:

- a Bash built-in: `help echo`
- a standalone executable: `which echo`

which can lead to some confusion.

Answer (score 2):

I finally properly format this string with `printf "$string"`. Thank you all.

Comment: What is this `$string` that you speak of? How is this connected to the question? What is does it not involve `\n` as in the other two answers?